# I do not have meta data in laravel's resources

Tags: laravel, resources

I my laravel 5 apps I returned json in request controls, like:

```
$retArray['tasks']          = $taskList;
$retArray['tasks_total_count'] = $tasks_total_count;
return response()->json($retArray, 200);
```

including additive parameters like tasks_total_count, which was used for pagination.

I laravel 6 app I use resources, like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\Admin;

use App\Facades\MyFuncsClass;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Task extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'price' => $this->price,
            ...
            'taskRequireSkills' => !empty($this->taskRequireSkills) ? $this->taskRequireSkills : [],
            'events' => !empty($this->events) ? $this->events : [],
            'events_count' => !empty($this->events_count) ? $this->events_count : 0,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            ...
        ];
    }

    public function with($request)
    {
        return [
            'meta' => [
                'version'=>'1.0.2'
            ]
        ];
    }

}
```

I want to add some additive meta data, like version
but in my browser I do not see this meta data, : https://prnt.sc/qm4t8y
Also which is correct way to add tasks_total_count parameter to my Resource, which is different for any request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a decision with as written here : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data
like :

```
class TaskCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $task
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($task)
    {

        return [
            $this->collection->transform(function($task){
                return [
                    'id' => $task->id,
                    'name' => $task->name,
                    'slug' => $task->slug,
                    ...
                    'date_start' => $task->date_start,
                    'date_end' => $task->date_end,
                    'created_at' => $task->created_at,
                    'updated_at' => $task->updated_at,
                ];
            }),
        ];

    }

    public function with($task)
    {
        return [
            'meta' => [
                'version'=>MyFuncsClass::getAppVersion()
            ]
        ];
    }
```